# Javascript error on vote up/down system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I've trying to adopt script for voting up and down with ajax and jquery from one tutorial. The problem `(I think)` is that in the tutorial the script is used with `jquery-2.1.1` but I use `jquery-1.10.1`
This is the HTML part

```
<div id="links-'.$row["image_id"].'">
    <input type="hidden" id="votes-'.$row["image_id"].'" value="'.$row["votes"].'">
    <input type="hidden" id="vote_rank_status-'.$row["image_id"].'" value="'.$vote_rank.'">
    <div class="btn-votes">
        <input type="button" title="Up" class="up" onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',"1")"'.$up.' />
        <div class="label-votes">'.$row["votes"].'</div>
            <input type="button" title="Down" class="down" onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',"-1")"'.$down.'/>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the `script.js` which should pass clicked button to add_vote.php

```
function addVote(image_id,vote_rank) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "add_vote.php",
        data:'image_id='+image_id+'&vote_rank='+vote_rank,
        type: "POST",
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#links-' + image_id + ' .pull-right').html("<img src='LoaderIcon.gif' />");
        },
        success: function(vote_rank_status){
            var votes = parseInt($('#votes-' + image_id).val());
            var vote_rank_status; // = parseInt($('#vote_rank_status-' + id).val());
            switch(vote_rank) {
                case "1":
                    votes = votes + 1;
                    // vote_rank_status = vote_rank_status + 1;
                    break;
                case "-1":
                    votes = votes-1;
                    //vote_rank_status = vote_rank_status - 1;
                    break;
            }
            $('#votes-' + image_id).val(votes);
            $('#vote_rank_status-' + image_id).val(vote_rank_status);

            var up, down;

            if (vote_rank_status == 1) {
                up = "disabled";
                down = "enabled";
            }

            if (vote_rank_status == -1) {
                up = "enabled";
                down = "disabled";
            }   

            var vote_button_html = '<input type="button" title="Up" id="up" onClick="addVote(' + image_id + ',\'1\')" ' + up + ' /><div class="label-votes">' + votes + '</div><input type="button" title="Down" id="down"  onClick="addVote(' + image_id + ',\'-1\')" ' + down + ' />';    
            $('#links-' + image_id + ' .pull-right').html(vote_button_html);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click vote up or down nothing happen on the page. Didn't add new vote and didn't insert into database.
This is what I see in console of firefox when I click on button

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got end of script

and this but I'm not sure if is relevant to this script. Showing that the error is in file `jquery-1.10.1.min.js`

> Empty string passed to getElementById().

Comment: create a fiddle, and wher you are using getElementById() ??

Comment: I will try. Just a sec

Comment: @AnirbanN, it's coming from jQuery, not OP's code

Comment: One (unrelated) issue i see is you're defining vote_rank_status inside the success function which has a parameter called vote_rank_status

Comment: How to create fiddle with this `script.js`?

Comment: This is the jsffidle but I'm not sure that is correct like this http://jsfiddle.net/c6dhe3re/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `onclick` functions appear to have syntax errors.

```
onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',"1")"
```

As you can see, you are using double quotes (around the number 1) inside double quotes. Try:

```
onClick="addVote('.$row['image_id'].',\"1\")"
```

Comment: Like this I've got now this in console `SyntaxError: illegal character` but how can I see which character is illegal?

Comment: I've got it to work. This `\"1\"` should be `\'1\'`. Thank you!